# bash run command based on a list of ip

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I created this bash script to run python code on each host listed in my `ip_list`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a ip_list=('10.99.1.1' '10.99.1.2' '10.99.1.3"' '10.99.1.4');

for i in $(ip_list) ; do 
    ssh -i ~/Downloads/abc.pem -t -t ec2-user@$i "sudo   python /home/user/abc.py"
done
```

But I got error:

```
Error: line 4: ip_list: command not found
```

What did I do wrong here? thanks

Comment: Use: `for i in "${ip_list[@]}" ; do` whereas `$(ip_list)` tries to run `ip_list` command

Answer (score 0):

as @anubhava suggests, try ${ip_list[@]}, like this:

```
declare -a ip_list=('10.99.1.1' '10.99.1.2' '10.99.1.3' '10.99.1.4');

for i in ${ip_list[@]} ; do
    ssh -i ~/Downloads/abc.pem -t -t ec2-user@$i "sudo   python /home/user/abc.py"
done
```